# Why is Clojure allowing me to redefine the same variable?

Tags: clojure

If the variables are immutable in Clojure, then why did it allow to redefine the same variable in the following snippet:

```
(ns tutorial.test-immutability-of-variables)

(defn test_if_variables_are_mutable
  []
  (def a 1)
  (def a 10)
  (println (format "Value of a: %d" a) )
  )

(test_if_variables_are_mutable)
```

The above code compiles and o/p is `10`.

Answer (score 3):

Clojure makes a distinction between *values* and *references to values*. Clojure guarantees that *values* are immutable.

Consider what happens when your function is evaluated:

```clj
(def a 1)
```

When the above form is evaluated, a Clojure Var is created (with name `a` and namespace `tutorial.test-immutability-of-variables`) and it is bound to the value 1.

```clj
(def a 10)
```

When this form is evaluated, the existing Clojure Var is rebound to the value 10.

Use of `def` within a function is strongly discouraged. Use `def` for top level forms only in your code. Alternatively for a lexically bound symbol use `let`.

The full story of what happens is a bit more involved than I've outlined above, see the [reference documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/vars) on Vars. There are other reference types in Clojure, such as [Atoms](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, you can change what the global `Var` points to, but you cannot change the original ***value***.  Here is another example:

```
(def x 42)

(defn changer-1
  []
  (println "changer-1: x - old" x)
  (let [x "Goodbye"] ; change a local variable
    (println "changer-1: x - new" x)))

(defn caller-1
  []
  (newline)
  (let [x "Hello"]
    (println "caller-1: x - before" x)
    (changer-1)
    (println "caller-1: x - after " x)))

(defn changer-2
  []
  (println "changer-2: x - old" x)
  (def x 666) ; reset the global Var (normally bad form)
  (println "changer-2: x - new" x))

(defn caller-2
  []
  (newline)
  (println "caller-2: Var x - before" x)
  (let [x "Hello"]
    (println "caller-2: x - before" x)
    (changer-2)
    (println "caller-2: x - after " x))
  (println "caller-2: Var x - after" x))


(caller-1)
(caller-2)
```

with result

```
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

caller-1: x - before Hello
changer-1: x - old 42
changer-1: x - new Goodbye
caller-1: x - after  Hello

caller-2: Var x - before 42
caller-2: x - before Hello
changer-2: x - old 42
changer-2: x - new 666
caller-2: x - after  Hello
caller-2: Var x - after 666
```

For more information, please see this [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) sources, especially "Getting Clojure" and "Brave Clojure"